# Microsoft Service Bus on a Windows Workgroup

Tags: servicebus

I just started playing with Microsoft Service Bus.  Now my personal challenge is that I'm doing this after hours, on my own time, etc, which means I am using VMs and Non-Domain pcs.  These guys are all workgroup.

I've had pretty decent success, especially after I stumbled across this link: [Microsoft Service Bus 1.0 unable to communicate with a server outside the client's domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179937/microsoft-service-bus-1-0-unable-to-communicate-with-a-server-outside-the-client)

This guy provided a much needed boost to get me past being able to use the namespace to create queues, etc.

However, went I get to the QueueClient.Send() function, I'm still getting (and I paraphrased that a bit).

```
"The token provider was unable to provide a security token while accessing 'https://Windows2008Server:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace/$STS/Windows/'. Token provider returned message: ''.
```

The same code from the link above is what I'm using for the message factory.  So my question becomes, does anybody have any ideas on how to get past this send to work?

If I can get past this little issue then I can start seeing what Service Bus can really do.

Thanks so much!

Nick

---

Same issue as before, changed my code to be this:

```
        TokenProvider localUserTokenProvider = WindowsTokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider(connBuilder.StsEndpoints,new System.Net.NetworkCredential("LocalServer", "LocalPassword"));

        MessagingFactory messageFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(connBuilder.GetAbsoluteRuntimeEndpoints(), localUserTokenProvider);
        NamespaceManager namespaceManager = new NamespaceManager(connBuilder.GetAbsoluteManagementEndpoints(), localUserTokenProvider);
```

So, it looks like I still need to have the same account on both of them...

Comment: I will add, I know the credentials are correct, based on the examples I found, I can successfully create/delete queues.  I just can't do a QueueClient.Send....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see. In that case, since you're using windows in both sides, you don't need the OAuthTokenProvider. You can use a Windows Token provider, just make sure of the following:
- The credentials you're passing must exist in the server
- Don't include any domain or workgroup information in the credential.

You need to configured it like this (the sample assumes you're using a config file for your connection strings):

```
TokenProvider localUserTokenProvider = WindowsTokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider(
            connBuilder.StsEndpoints,
            new System.Net.NetworkCredential (userName, password));
```

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj714802%28v=azure.10%29.aspx#BMK_SBDev2) has more information on how to work 'offline' with Service Bus Server.

Answer (score 2):

If your client and your server are on different machines, you might have a certificate trust problem. You have to export the Service Bus Server CA from your server machine by using  is installed, open the Service Bus for Windows Server PowerShell console and use the *Get-SBAutoGeneratedCA* cmdlet, and then import it in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store of your client machine.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj192993%28v=azure.10%29.aspx) has more information on how to export / import them to enable the remote client scenario.

Comment: Client & Server are on different machines, same workgroup.  I'll try removing the SB cert and reexporting/importing it.  Maybe I screwed that part up.

Comment: Do you think the cert would be the issue if I'm able to using the namespace commands to remove a queue, recreate a queue, etc?  That part I can do without issue.

Comment: It's possible. The management operations (create, delete queues, etc...) go through one set of APIs, while the runtime operations go through another. There might be some differences on how they deal with certificate validations.

Comment: Ramiro, thanks so much for the help, unfortunately, that didn't solve the send issue.  Same message as before. :(   Re-exported the certs, imported them just fine, same problem.

Comment: I figured out what was going on, at least to an extent....

I have to hit the W2k8 server with the same credentials that I'm logged into my Win8 box (dev) with.

If I try to send in the parameters like this:

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was going on, at least to an extent....

I have to hit the W2k8 server with the same credentials that I'm logged into my Win8 box (dev) with.

If I try to send in the parameters like this:

```
//namespaceManager.Settings.TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(new Uri[] { new Uri("https://ServerName:9355") }, new NetworkCredential("ServerLocalUser", "ServerLocalUserPwd", "ServerName"));
//messageFactory.GetSettings().TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateOAuthTokenProvider(new Uri[] { new Uri("https://ServerName:9355") }, new NetworkCredential("ServerLocalUser", "ServerLocalPWD", "ServerName"));
```

Then it won't work.  Any ideas why it's sending in my logged in credentials and not using the ServerLocalUser/Pwd/Name combination?

I found this by looking in the event logs...

Comment: I'm at the same place as you. I'm glad to know there is at least a work around for this. You would think that if you set the credentials that they would carry over.  Please update us if you find anything else out!

Comment: I ran into this last night - I think the problem is "messageFactory.GetSettings().TokenProvider =" in all the examples. That doesn't seem to actually set the TokenProvider. I created a MessagingFactorySettings object, set the TokenProvider on that, and passed it into the MessagingFactory.Create() method. That seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get things to work.

I started out creating the same local user account on both my dev machine (Win8/Studio2012) and my server (Win2k8R2).  I exported the client cert that's referenced above (2 or 3 times actually) and imported as needed.  Once I got a good connection working, I started backing things out.  Deleted the local account on my Win8 box, etc.  Then it all started magically working.

A few things about my environ.  I'm doing all of this with VMWare Fusion.  (Yep Fusion).  The VM Machines are all configured with NAT on the networking, no static IPs.

Don't know how, but it's working.  I did just messages first. I figure if I can get messages working then I can go after Pub/Sub topics... That's next.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.ServiceBus;
    using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Net.Security;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Security;

    namespace Test_Service_Bus
    {
        public static class Util
        {

            public static void SetCertificatePolicy()
            {
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += RemoteCertificateValidate;
            }

            private static bool RemoteCertificateValidate(object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Warning, trust any certificate");
                return true;
            }
        }

        class Program
        {

            static string ServerFQDN = "SVRNICK"; //System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).HostName;
            static int HttpPort = 9355;
            static int TcpPort = 9354;
            static string ServiceNameSpace = "ServiceBusDefaultNamespace";
            const string QueueName = "ServiceBusQueueSample";

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                SDKVersion();

            }


            static void SDKVersion()
            {

                ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder connBuilder = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder();
                connBuilder.ManagementPort = HttpPort;
                connBuilder.RuntimePort = TcpPort;

                connBuilder.Endpoints.Add(new UriBuilder() { Scheme = "sb", Host = ServerFQDN, Path = ServiceNameSpace }.Uri);
                connBuilder.StsEndpoints.Add(new UriBuilder() { Scheme = "https", Host = ServerFQDN, Port = HttpPort, Path = ServiceNameSpace }.Uri);

                TokenProvider localUserTokenProvider = WindowsTokenProvider.CreateWindowsTokenProvider(connBuilder.StsEndpoints, new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ServerLocalAcct", "ServerLocalPassword"));

                MessagingFactory messageFactory = MessagingFactory.Create(connBuilder.GetAbsoluteRuntimeEndpoints(), localUserTokenProvider);
                NamespaceManager namespaceManager = new NamespaceManager(connBuilder.GetAbsoluteManagementEndpoints(), localUserTokenProvider);

                NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connBuilder.ToString());


                if (namespaceManager == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nUnexpected error: NamespaceManager is NULL");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Checking if queue exists");
                if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Queue exists, let's delete it so we can start over again");
                    namespaceManager.DeleteQueue(QueueName);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("And create a new queue");
                namespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueName);



                // create a message client
                QueueClient myQueueClient = messageFactory.CreateQueueClient(QueueName);

                Console.WriteLine("Feeding messages");
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 100 == 0)
                        Console.WriteLine("Messages sent: {0}", i.ToString());

                    // send to message broker
                    using (BrokeredMessage sendMessage = new BrokeredMessage("Hello world. " + i.ToString()))
                    {
                        sendMessage.Label = "Label_" + i.ToString(); ;
                        myQueueClient.Send(sendMessage);
                    }


                }

                BrokeredMessage receivedMessage = myQueueClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

                while (receivedMessage != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Message Received: Body={0}", receivedMessage.GetBody<string>()));
                    receivedMessage.Complete();

                    receivedMessage = myQueueClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                }

                // Close things down.
                Console.WriteLine("Closing down message");
                if (messageFactory != null)
                {
                    messageFactory.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```